# Kernel Oops 17 for ARM

Tags: linux, loops, null, arm, panic

For a few days, I have investigated this problem, but knowing hardly could not be.

linux version : 2.6.39
board : at91sam9x25
Processor : ARM926EJ-S rev 5

After the process has been run successfully for more than one day, displays the message oops suddenly.

look at the r0. it is measns struct kmem_cache pointer.

keme_cache pointer was initialized when linux booting.

Then the r0 is should never change.

but the oops message, the r0 is 0.. it is impossible

i don't know why the r0 was changed to 0.

i want how to debugging or answer

please help me.

```
Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000
pgd = cfb1c000
[00000000] *pgd=2fbfa831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1]
last sysfs file: 
Modules linked in:
CPU: 0 Not tainted (2.6.39 #216)
PC is at kmem_cache_alloc+0x24/0x98
LR is at getname_flags+0x20/0xe8
pc : [] lr : [] psr: 40000093
sp : cfbb5f40 ip : 00000000 fp : 00000000
r10: 00000000 r9 : cfbb4000 r8 : ffffff9c
r7 : 00000000 r6 : 00000000 r5 : 40000013 r4 : 40202e7e
r3 : 40000093 r2 : 00000100 r1 : 000000d0 r0 : 00000000
Flags: nZcv IRQs off FIQs on Mode SVC_32 ISA ARM Segment user
Control: 0005317f Table: 2fb1c000 DAC: 00000015
Process MEG (pid: 589, stack limit = 0xcfbb4270)
Stack: (0xcfbb5f40 to 0xcfbb6000)
5f40: 00000000 40202e7e 00000000 00000000 00000000 c00a1e9c 00014220 00000001
5f60: 00000000 00000000 00000005 c0094efc 00000000 00000011 00000000 00000000
5f80: 00000024 00000100 00000000 00000000 4020e040 4020dee0 00000005 c0030b28
5fa0: 00000000 c0030980 00000000 4020e040 40202e7e 00000000 00000000 00000050
5fc0: 00000000 4020e040 4020dee0 00000005 402123dc 00000000 be3ffea0 00000000
5fe0: 40202e87 be3ffd58 401d949c 401c3010 60000010 40202e7e 00000000 00000000
[] (kmem_cache_alloc+0x24/0x98) from [] (getname_flags+0x20/0xe8)
[] (getname_flags+0x20/0xe8) from [] (do_sys_open+0xa8/0x1ac)
[] (do_sys_open+0xa8/0x1ac) from [] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x2c)
Code: e0016003 e10f5000 e3853080 e121f003 (e5901000) 
---[ end trace d33e1f5c547d52cb ]---
Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000
pgd = c0004000
[00000000] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 17 [#2]
last sysfs file: 
Modules linked in:
CPU: 0 Tainted: G D (2.6.39 #216)
PC is at kmem_cache_free+0x18/0xcc
LR is at rcu_process_callbacks+0x6c/0x84
```

> Blockquote

```
pc : [] lr : [] psr: 20000093
sp : cf833f68 ip : cf833f30 fp : 00000000
r10: 00000000 r9 : c0058dc4 r8 : cfbff540
r7 : 20000013 r6 : c042df1c r5 : cfbff540 r4 : cfbbf760
r3 : 20000093 r2 : 00000000 r1 : cfbff540 r0 : 00000000
Flags: nzCv IRQs off FIQs on Mode SVC_32 ISA ARM Segment kernel
Control: 0005317f Table: 2fb1c000 DAC: 00000017
Process rcu_kthread (pid: 6, stack limit = 0xcf832270)
Stack: (0xcf833f68 to 0xcf834000)
3f60: cfbbf760 cfbff540 c042df1c cf833f94 cf833fa0 c00705d0
3f80: cf815040 cf815040 cf832000 c00706a4 c031057c 00000000 cf815040 c0058dc4
3fa0: cf833fa0 cf833fa0 cf833fd4 cf81bf74 00000000 c00705e8 00000000 00000000
3fc0: 00000000 c0058a04 c003185c 00000000 00000000 00000000 cf833fd8 cf833fd8
3fe0: 00000000 cf81bf74 c0058984 c003185c 00000013 c003185c 00020018 18000004
[] (kmem_cache_free+0x18/0xcc) from [] (rcu_process_callbacks+0x6c/0x84)
[] (rcu_process_callbacks+0x6c/0x84) from [] (rcu_kthread+0xbc/0xe4)
[] (rcu_kthread+0xbc/0xe4) from [] (kthread+0x80/0x88)
[] (kthread+0x80/0x88) from [] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
Code: e1a08001 e10f7000 e3873080 e121f003 (e5904000) 
---[ end trace d33e1f5c547d52cc ]---
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
[] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xec) from [] (panic+0x4c/0x180)
[] (panic+0x4c/0x180) from [] (die+0x180/0x1c4)
[] (die+0x180/0x1c4) from [] (__do_kernel_fault+0x64/0x84)
[] (__do_kernel_fault+0x64/0x84) from [] (do_page_fault+0x1b8/0x1d0)
[] (do_page_fault+0x1b8/0x1d0) from [] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x94)
[] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x94) from [] (__dabt_svc+0x4c/0x60)
Exception stack(0xcf833f20 to 0xcf833f68)
3f20: 00000000 cfbff540 00000000 20000093 cfbbf760 cfbff540 c042df1c 20000013
3f40: cfbff540 c0058dc4 00000000 00000000 cf833f30 cf833f68 c00705d0 c0093080
3f60: 20000093 ffffffff
[] (__dabt_svc+0x4c/0x60) from [] (kmem_cache_free+0x18/0xcc)
[] (kmem_cache_free+0x18/0xcc) from [] (rcu_process_callbacks+0x6c/0x84)
[] (rcu_process_callbacks+0x6c/0x84) from [] (rcu_kthread+0xbc/0xe4)
[] (rcu_kthread+0xbc/0xe4) from [] (kthread+0x80/0x88)
[] (kthread+0x80/0x88) from [] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
```

Comment: It looks like a regular kernel memory allocator corruption. It may have been caused by any driver or some kernel bug. If you are serious about the problem you should arm yourself with "crash" tool, however that might not be trivial if you aren't a novice with kernel and its tools.

Comment: All of your code addresses are missing.  Verifying the call stack makes sense is important.  It looks like `c = __this_cpu_ptr(s->cpu_slab);` is where your BUSERR happens.  Is it possible you have bad memory on the device?

Comment: @artlessnoise sorry. i don't know well. i need research on this code